# Teachable Machineでローカルファイルを読み込む方法について

Tags: 機械学習

Teachable MachineのAudio Projectで、学習データとしてローカルファイルを使いたいのですが、
You can only upload zip files with audio data previously created/downloaded with Teachable Machine.
と出てしまいます。

実際にTeachable Machineで録音し、ダウンロードしたzipファイルの中身を見てみましたが、webmファイルとjsonファイルが入っています。
webmファイルは音声ファイルなので問題ありませんが、jsonファイルは冒頭に「FrequencyFrame」と書いてあり、その後に実数が羅列されていて何を表しているのかわかりません。

どうにかjsonファイルを作り出し、読み込ませる方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: エラーメッセージは、

Answer (score 0):

「webmファイルは音声ファイルなので問題ありませんが」と書かれていますが、webMは動画のフォーマットなので、webMファイルは音声ファイルとは言えないと思います。

[WEBM MP3 変換 - オーディオファイルをオンラインで変換する](https://www.aconvert.com/jp/audio/webm-to-mp3/)のようなサイトとか、webMから音声ファイルを生成するアプリを使って、webMファイルからMP3ファイル(音声ファイル)を作成し、それをZIPで圧縮したものをTeachable MachineのAudio Projectのクラスにアップロード(Drag&Drop)してみては、如何でしょうか？